# Log Messages In Juniper MX960

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-mx, cli, syslog

How do I check the Log Messages of Last Month on juniper MX960 Router.

When I am typing the command:

```
#show log Messages.
```

It's just showing me the messages for last 15 days. We have two MX960 Routers on one when I am entering the command, it's showing me the Logs for more than one month but on the redundant it's just showing for last 15 days.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of the show log command is `show log "filename"`.

First try:

`show log`

This command will show you all files in the log directory.

You will probably get the log entries you want simply by typing:

`show log messages.0.gz`

No need to think about decompressing the file. Junos will do this for you.